# Spring Boot : Getting IllegalArgumentException in WLS

Tags: java, spring-boot, weblogic, logback

I am trying to deploy spring boot as war in WLS 12 C and I am getting the below error,
I have skipped logging in pom.xml

```
          <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
```

and I have the below code in weblogic.xml

```
 <wls:container-descriptor>
            <wls:prefer-application-packages>
                <wls:package-name>org.slf4j.*</wls:package-name>
            </wls:prefer-application-packages>
        </wls:container-descriptor>
```

Please suggest is there any solution for the below Error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object of class [null] must be an instance of interface javax.management.MBeanServer
```

I have tried the below example

```
https://github.com/purrox/Spring-example
```

Answer (score 0):

The sample project `spring-example` is using a very old version of `spring-boot:1.0.0.RC4`. If you are using the same version as the sample project I advise you to upgrade to the latest stable spring-boot version `1.5.3`

**Edit**

> To deploy a Spring Boot application to WebLogic you must ensure that your servlet initializer **directly** implements WebApplicationInitializer (even if you extend from a base class that already implements it).

A typical initializer for WebLogic would be something like this:

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

}
```

Please refer to spring-boot documentation for [Deploying a WAR to WebLogic](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html#howto-weblogic)

Comment: Thanks, I have tried to add the changes with 1.5.3 and it is deploying, but from the port 7001 I am not able to consume my REST service calls. Please suggest Is there any other changes required after deploying and starting the application